# NGINX HTTP2 Push - Angular

Tags: angular, nginx, http2

We have an Angular app which hashes assets as part of the build output (e.g. *runtime.e44ca0c6491d9325714a.js* ).  The hash is necessary given frequent app updates.  The app is hosted on an NGINX server and we want to enable http2 push for these assets.

Is there a way to do "fuzzy" http2_push?

For example, we want to do something like:

```
 http2_push runtime.**.js;
 http2_push polyfills.**.js;
```

Where can I find info on achieving this outcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do like this. 
Moreover, I'd recommend you to use http2 server push for static data with care.
It would be better (from a performance point of view) to use browser's caсh than server push.

Read this - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1K0NykTXBbbbTlv60t5MyJvXjqKGsCVNYHyLEXIxYMv0/edit#heading=h.ke8t5vjw3jh4

You may take a look at this package - https://github.com/google/node-fastify-auto-push how the author implement server push and how the code makes a decision to push resource or not.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Welcome. You may mark the post as an answer, though :-)